# C++ to C# Code Conversion Types

Tags: c#, c++

I am trying to convert the following to C# but I am not getting expected results.

C++ Code:

```
DWORD CCSKW::GetCS(CString strFile)
{
    try
    {
        CFile file(strFile, CFile::modeRead);
        WORD wTemp = 0;
        WORD wCS = 0;

        const UINT uiMaxCharRead = 2000;
        TCHAR c[uiMaxCharRead];
        UINT uiCharRead;

        #ifdef _UNICODE
            while(uiCharRead = file.Read(c, uiMaxCharRead))
            {
                for(UINT i=0; i < uiCharRead; i++)
                    wCS ^= c[0];
            }
        #else
            while(uiCharRead = file.Read(c, uiMaxCharRead))
            {
                for(UINT i=0; i < uiCharRead-1; i++)
                {
                    wTemp = c[i];
                    i++;
                    wTemp <<= 8;
                    wTemp   += c[i];
                    wCS ^= wTemp;
                }
            }
        #endif
        file.Close();
        return (DWORD)wCS;
    }
    catch(CFileException *e)
    {
        e->ReportError();           
        e->Delete();                
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Briefly what this code does is reads a value from a binary file and returns it. This value is then used for a checksum calculation method.

My C# Code:

```
public UInt32 GetCS()
{
    try
    {
        ushort wTemp = 0;
        ushort wCS = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2000];

        int count;
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(csFile, FileMode.Open))
        {
            while ((count = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
                {
                    wTemp = buffer[i];
                    i++;
                    wTemp <<= 8;
                    wTemp += buffer[i];
                    wCS ^= wTemp;
                }
            }
        }
        return Convert.ToUInt32(wCS);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know it might be difficult to help without knowing all the code, but I would just like to know if I am on the right track or if I have made some obvious errors.

Thank you!

Comment: C# characters are Unicode.

Comment: I am not sure that this is you problem, but just in case want to draw your attention to the fact that in C# (and .NET in general) all strings are **always** encoded in UTF16

Comment: Can you share a binary file as example?

Comment: If you just want to read a binary file, how about using `byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("myfile.bin");` ?

Comment: @PaulStelian Not just unicode but specifically utf16., as I mentioned in my comment

Comment: The `C++` code for handling Unicode is clearly wrong, but I suspect it will be dong the `#else` part. I don't think Unicode is relevant here anyway, since this code is operating on bytes, not chars.

Comment: Use StreamReader with encoding UTF8 : StreamReader fs = new StreamReader("file", Encoding.UTF8);

Comment: Can you confirm if `_UNICODE` is defined for the C++ build? If it is, the C++ code will be wrong (and different from the C# code). Unless, of course, you really *meant* to repeatedly XOR only the first char in the buffer..

Comment: @MatthewWatson I just did a search for _UNICODE in the C++ project and it's not defined anywhere. Just #ifdefs.

Comment: So i've made a dummy file here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=06381051933519092914 Using the method in the post on this file, you should get a return value of 0x3336. With my C# code I get 0x3B36. Incidently, the last two hex are correct with the c# code.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes, that UNICODE code did look very suspect. I imagine it was either not completed or forgotten. Either way, it's not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the C++ code is using `TCHAR`, which is a signed 8-bit type, but the C# code is using `byte`, which is an unsigned 8-bit type.

That means this line of code:

```
wTemp += buffer[i];
```

will always increase the value of `wTemp` in the C# code because `buffer[i]` is unsigned, but in the C++ code it will decrease the value of `wTemp` for values of `buffer[i] >= 0x80`.

You can fix this by changing the offending line to:

```
unchecked { wTemp = (ushort)(wTemp + (sbyte)buffer[i]); }
```

After doing that, your sample file will produce a result of `0x3336`, as expected.

Comment: Wonderful! Coming from a pure web javascript background, I sometimes find it difficult to see what may be very obvious to some when it comes to types! Thank you very much for your help!